# VirtualBox is exist a logic bug that between storageattach with registervm

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

Background info：

Two files:

**xxx.vbox** is used to register the VM host in the Virtualbox.
**xxx.vdi** is a disk that used to register as a virtual disk.

I want to register the above both, but they are mutually exclusive.

---

command line：

```
> VBoxManage.exe storageattach "Ubuntu-Lite" --storagectl 

VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Ubuntu-Lite'(Need a vm name.)

> VBoxManage registervm "..\Ubuntu-Lite\Ubuntu-Lite.vbox"

VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find an open hard disk with UUID {9a69f2a6-6199-49f6-825e-58eb29a82db4}
(Need a disk.)
```

How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

On the vm files store directory lost a file that named by xxx.vbox-prev.

Find it，then use the registervm command to register the VM directly.